# ASP NET CORE - net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 206

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, protocols, http2

I am getting this type of error since past week.
The error is this:

```
net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 206
```

The error persists in our development server which is deployed on a Windows Server 2012 R2.
It happens with js, css and image files.

The website deployed in the development server redirects through nginx and there is a different IP for that.

Possible cause of the problem might be that nginx is obfuscating the development server to serve the local images, files, etc and blocks the request headers from delivering the content.

This is the response I get from one of the files which are being served from the local directory in the development server:

```
Request URL: https://example.com/Img/xxx.jpg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 206 
Remote address: x.x.x.x:xxx
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Request headers are:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 1
content-range: bytes 32510-32510/566516
content-type: image/jpeg
date: Mon, 03 Apr 2023 11:17:16 GMT
etag: "1d735f9bae54674"
last-modified: Tue, 20 Apr 2021 15:27:53 GMT
server: openresty
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
x-served-by: xxx.com
```

Therefore there is the `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` which actually doesn't make a lot of sense because in our nginx manager the `HTTP/2` option is disabled.
If anyone has ever faced same technical difficulty  and can point me to some solution, that would be delightful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was easy finally. Just by rebooting the nginx manager solved the issue eventually.